# How come my vector is changing after I pass it through a constructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

If you look at the output you can see what listOrder's contents are, and these are the correct contents. However as soon as I pass it into my graph constructor and output the same list I have jibberish. I suspect this has something to do with my graphs adjacencyList of Vertex* contents, but I don't understand how my pointers are being jumbled. Please help me to get the correct nodes into the graph vector!

```
for (vector<char>::iterator it=listOrder.begin(); it!=listOrder.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << "ListNode: " << *it << endl;
}
Graph graph(listOrder, adjacencyList);
for (vector<char>::iterator it=graph.getOrder().begin(); it!=graph.getOrder().end(); ++it)
{
    cout << "Node: " << *it << endl;
}
```

Constructor

```
Graph::Graph(vector<char> newVertices, map<char, Vertex*> newAL)
{
vertices = newVertices;
adjacencyList = newAL;
}
```

GetOrder function

```
vector<char> Graph::getOrder()
{
return vertices;
}
```

Output

```
ListNode: A
ListNode: B
ListNode: C
ListNode: D
ListNode: E
ListNode: F
ListNode: G
Node: ░
Node: ↨
Node: >
Node:
Node: ─
Node:
Node: >
```

Comment: I don't see you outputting the same list, I see two different lists. Explain yourself better please, and add a little more code for the `getOrder` function.

Comment: Already added that code

Comment: Have you tried valgrind?

Comment: No, I have ddd though I'll run it through that and see if it indicates anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a copy of the vector every time `getOrder` is called, so the iterators aren't from the same container.

Either return the vector from `getOrder` by reference or only call `getOrder` once to get a copy of the vector and then iterate through that.

Something like:

```
vector<char> v(graph.getOrder());
for (vector<char>::iterator it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << "Node: " << *it << endl;
}
```

Comment: Definitely this was the problem

Comment: Good catch! I missed this one completely.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the range-based for.  It will help you avoid some of the problems that you're running into.

Your getOrder function is returning a different vector on each call, which means that you can't validly compare the iterators from one call to another.

If you rework your code so it's something like this:

```
for (auto &it : listOrder)
{
    cout << "ListNode: " << it << endl;
}
Graph graph(listOrder, adjacencyList);
for (auto &it : graph.getOrder())
{
    cout << "Node: " << it << endl;
}
```

It will have a better chance of working.

Comment: This won't compile without giving the type of the iterator. Also, range based for loops aren't allowed in C++ 98 which is what I need this to work with

Comment: ok, but you still need to avoid comparing iterators from different calls to getOrder().

Comment: If I'm comparing on the value and not the address why is that a problem?

Comment: Because each call to getOrder() returns a new, and different vector.

Comment: Gotcha I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

use the copy constructor for initialization of your class memebers

```
Graph::Graph(vector<char> newVertices, map<char, Vertex*> newAL)
: vertices(newVertices)
, adjacencyList(newAL)
{}
```

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't fix the issue :(